# Is there any significant reason to use the ordinal of an enum in a switch case, instead of using the enum?

Tags: java, enums, ordinal, ordinals

I recently came across the following example:

```
CommandKey key = command.getKey();
    switch(key.ordinal()) {
    case 1:
        return IncidentType.StatusChange;
    case 2:
        return IncidentType.Notification;
    ...
```

Where the key is an enum.

Is there any reason why whoever wrote this did it as such, because this appears to make the code unnecessarily brittle; changes to the values of the enum list could potentially break the mapping logic and result in an incorrect return type.
The only possible benefit I can see is slight performance gains, which in the context of a server with high throughput could justify the adopted methodology.

Are any possible performance gains worth it, and are there any other benefits I am unaware of?

Comment: I'd bet that whoever wrote this was not aware that you can just switch on enums. I don't think there's any benefit and that there's any performance gain.

Comment: BTW `key` might be `null` and the ordinal starts at `0`

Comment: I know ordinals are meant to start at zero but... For some absurd reason which I can't work out, the ordinal returned matches as if it started at 1. I can't post the exact code though because of company policy, but still, I have no idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good reason *against* it. The ordinals can change any time without breaking even binary compatibility. The names cannot so change at all.

A better solution would have been to build the returned values into the `Enum` itself.

Comment: I considered suggesting modifying the enum, but it seems to me from the context that the two aren't closely bound (e.g., this is in the genre of a green-screen UI).

Answer (score 2):

No, this shouldn't be used. The most charitable interpretation is that someone was blindly copying code from C or C++ with `#define`s, but it should have been made idiomatic.

Furthermore, in a case such as outlined in the question (understanding that the real code could be more complicated), this would best be solved with a simple `EnumMap`, which would be much more performant than any branch.

Comment: I am not sure that an EnumMap would be simpler or faster than a `switch` used appropriately in all use cases.  In this case, if a value is always returned it would certainly be cleaner.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Of course not in all cases, thus the caveat.